# Do partial variables override helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I have some helper method that called `current_language` and sometimes I send `current_language` in the `local_assigns`.

So I want to assign my partial variable by the `local_assigns`'s `current_language` in case if it's sent.

But I found something weird, in the following code:

```
<%
  binding.pry
  x = 4

  current_language = local_assigns[:current_language] || current_language
%>
```

In line 3 when debugging `current_language` equals `nil` even before overriding.

I expect it shall still equal the helper method until it's overrided.

So what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s well-documented feature of the language. The variable is kinda hoisted. Use this code to explicitly tell the parser where is the variable and where is the method call:

```
#                                                                      ⇓⇓
current_language = local_assigns[:current_language] || current_language()
```

Comment: Thank you!
But how `current_language` is overrided when checked it in line 3 before even overriding it?

Comment: Shall it be overrided in line 5 or am I missing something?

Comment: Follow the links in the referenced answer and google for “variable hoisting.”